# ModuleNotFoundError when creating RSA program

Tags: python-3.x, pycrypto

(Python 3.7)
A ModuleNotFoundError arises when I try to import Crypto.PublicKey:

```
import crypto
from crypto.PublicKey import RSA

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    from crypto.PublicKey import RSA
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 73, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util.py3compat import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I had to import Crypto as crypto (lowercase) otherwise

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import Crypto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

So, how do I correctly import the RSA function in PublicKey in Crypto?

Comment: Have you done `pip install pycrypto`?

Comment: `pip3 install pycrypto` (`pip` doesn't work on my system, have to use `pip3`)

Comment: I also have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling it:
`pip3 uninstall pycrypto;pip3 install pycrypto`

Comment: Nevermind, I just renamed the module in the library from `crypto` to `Crypto`, which allowed me to `import Crypto`